# A rest element type must be an array type for generic type in typescript

Tags: typescript

In the code below

```
const f = <
  Args extends any[] = never
>(...args: Args) => {
  const foo: [number, number, ...Args] = [0, 0, ...args]
}
```

tsc does not like `[number, number, ...Args]` even though I thought I was constraining the type to be an array with `Args extends any[]`

i get this error

> A rest element type must be an array type

Comment: I think a generic type parameter does not satisfy the "must be an array type" constraint. Don't think there is a good way around this in the general case. Could you provide a larger example as to what you want to do with `foo` that requires `Args` to be spread into `foo`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir but it works in the function argument type context

Comment: @zerkms not 100% sure what you mean. If you are referring to the fact that at call site you get an array type, that is true, but generally the compiler can do a lot more when all the types are known and not just constrained type parameter

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I mean that it looks inconsistent that `(...args: Args)` is okay for the rest arguments, but it's not okay for `...Args` for the rest of array destructuring.

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh i did not down vote

Comment: although I know `[...any[]]` works, that is what I am currently using

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh I think you need to stop worrying about the downvote

Answer (score 2):

If you use Typescript 4.0 or newer, this code works fine. You can upgrade to make it compile.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1):

```
type Args = any[];

const f = (...args: Args) => {
  const foo: [number, number, ...Args] = [0, 0, ...args]
}
```

Comment: Um that changes the meaning of the original code. for `Args = [string, string]` your version produces `[number, number, [string, string]]` the original version would produce `[number, number, string, string]`.

Comment: Not my downvote... I rarely downvote except for erouneoys information.

Comment: Doesn't it look like a bug then?