# Can I express this higher-order function signature in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, signature, higher-order-functions

I have the following function:

```js
const fn = async (bool, num, str) => {
  // ...
};
```

- `bool` is a boolean,
- `num` is a number
- `str` is an *optional* string

I also have the following HOF that allows populating that last *optional* parameter at call-time if it hasn't been passed through by the caller:

```js
const hof = (callback) => {
  return async (...args) => {
    if (args.length) {
      const lastArg = args[args.length - 1];
      if ("string" === typeof lastArg) {
        return callback(...args);
      }
    }
    const s = await findString();
    return callback(...[...args].concat(s));
  };
};
```

This allows writing:

```js
const fn = hof(async (bool, num, str) => {
  // str will be valued, either by the caller, or by the hof
});
```

---

How can I fully type `hof`, knowing that it is not aware of the callback's parameters (i.e. they can differ from one usage to another)? Is this even possible with TypeScript?

I managed to deal with the returned type via generics:

```js
const hof = <R>(
  callback: (...args: any) => Promise<R>
): (...args: any) => Promise<R> => {
  return async (...args) => {
    // ...
  };
};
```

But can those dynamic parameters be typed, so that when using `const fn = hof(async (bool, num, str) => { ... });`, `fn` will only accept parameters according to the callback ones? The only difference between the `fn` signature and the callback one, is that `fn` allows an undefined `str` last parameter while the callback has it mandatory.

Not compiling, but something along those lines:

```js
const hof = <R>(
  callback: (...args: ???, s: string) => Promise<R>
): (...args: ???, s?: string) => Promise<R> => {
  return async (...args) => {
    // ...
  };
};
```

---

Just in case of I'm hitting an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), the real-life usage is [MySQL transaction management](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#transactions). This pattern allows me to start a new transaction automatically if no connection is passed through, or use the caller's connection if it started a transaction already. This implementation is being discussed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/243607/12849), but in a nutshell, that my real-life `hof`:

```js
const transactional = (run) => async (...args) => {
  if (args.length) {
    const lastArg = args[args.length - 1];
    if (lastArg && "PoolConnection" === lastArg.constructor.name) {
      return run(...args);
    }
  }
  return _transactional(async (connection) => run(...[...args].concat(connection)));
};
```

Shout if you're thinking of a better approach ;)

Comment: Asa side-note `"String" === lastArg.constructor.name` is *most likely wrong*. If you're checking for a string primitive, it's enough to do `typeof lastArg === "string"`. The only reason to check the constructor name is if you're checking for a String *object*. However, for that 1. you can use `lastArg instanceof String` 2. you most likely shouldn't be using string objects.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, good point, my simplified example isn't great. IRL, I'm checking whether that param is an instance of PoolConnection as shown in the last section, but this type isn't exposed by the mysql lib, so I had to play around with the constructor name instead, unless you're thinking of a better approach?

Comment: Hmm, probably worth a separate question for that. I'd definitely try to expose it, so you can use `instanceof`, however.

Comment: Just a quick question, when you say sql transaction, is it possible for multiple calls, because unfortunately with node been async, transaction wouldn't be serialised the way you might expect especially using the same connection object.

Comment: It seems like this is a little like a partial application in reverse; we could abstract this a little further to have a HOF that takes some function, and returns a function which does not take the last argument?

Comment: @OliverRadini I think we could type this, but putting the argument at the end is a bit more difficult (requires recursive type aliases) would you be willing to move the transaction argument to the start ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir This is the problem I was having when looking at this - you can have a type `[string ...T[]]` but the rest parameter must be last

Comment: @OliverRadini what about flipping the arguments order in the HOF? (or [*with* a HOF](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flip))

Comment: @Keith I've updated the question with the full SQL transaction management functions I'm currently using, feel free to shout if you see something that doesn't look right. Let's try to keep this question about pure TS typing though if you don't mind, I'll raise another one about SQL transaction specifically if you believe something's wrong :)

Comment: @OliverRadini Sorry, I'm quite new to TypeScript, but if it does not need optional parameters to be the last ones, then I wouldn't mind modifying their order if this simplifies it. I think it makes sense to have it last though in my case, but if the only way to have proper typing is to modify the order, then so be it :)

Comment: @VLAZ Yes indeed - it may be best solved using a function overload to solve the partial application, then just having a flip HOF to get the correct order.

Comment: @sp00m  If the function `_transactional` can be called concurrently then yes, the above can potentially fail.  For example if say you was using this for an express application, and 2 different web users execute something that's going to require this at the same time, things will get funcky.  There are ways around this, but yes a different questions might be better here.

Comment: @Keith, I created https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/243607/12849, feel free to comment there :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you'll struggle to achieve this in typescript, at least, it'll be difficult as it is now. I'd like to be able to come in with a proper answer but I've not been able to find a good solution.

Part of the problem is trying to define a HOF that takes arguments of any length and type, but always with a string. It's somewhat easier to define your functions as taking objects with given properties, for instance, as:

```js
interface IWithConnection {
    connection?: string;
}

interface IFnArgs {
    bool: boolean;
    num: number;
}

const findString = async () => 'a-connection';

const injectConnection = async <T extends IWithConnection, U>(fn: (x: T) => U) => {
    return async (x: IWithConnection & T) => {
        if (x.connection !== undefined) {
            return fn(x);
        }

        const connection = await findString();

        return fn({ connection, ...x });
    };
};

const fn = ({ bool, num, connection }: IFnArgs & IWithConnection) => `${bool} ${num} ${connection}`;

const fn_ = injectConnection(fn);
```

I appreciate that this is quite a different implementation to that which you have in your question, but it's the closest I could get.

The problem with the original solution is that we have a hard time defining a function that takes args which are `[string, ...T]`, [because we can't spread generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267445/a-rest-element-type-must-be-an-array-type-for-generic-type-in-typescript), even if we assert that `T extends []`. Further, we can't define args as `[...T[], string]`, because the rest parameter must be the last parameter.

We can provide a workable type when a function takes arguments all of the same type, because we can type it as: `[string, ...T[]]`. This would be very limiting, though.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation. What do you think about `({ bool, num }, connection)`, i.e. moving the `connection` out of the input object? This would allow having `fn_` returning `(T, connection?) => R` while the callback would be signed with `(T, connection) => R`, making more explicit that `connection` will always be valued from within the callback?

Comment: @sp00m I think that'd work great - the difficulty comes from the fact that it's quite difficult to express an array of multiple types in typescript, which here causes a problem when we want to describe `args` - we can say `[string, ...T[]]`, but then all args 1-n would need to be the same type, which we don't want. `({ bool, num }, connection)` means the signature can be `(T, string)` which is far easier to type